# CMS Page content not displaying on Website

Tags: magento-1.9

Added a new page under **CMS --> Pages**
Title: Portfolio 
URL Key: portfolio

However on website it does not display.
[image]

I checked back-end **Catalog --> URL Rewrite Management**

```
Type: System
ID Path: Category/45
Request Path: portfolio1.html
Target Path: Catalog/category/view/id/45
Redirect: No
```

Please help.

Comment: what it says when you tried to open the URL? 404?

Comment: Yes. I added picture in question.

Comment: Check once with Redirect :yes At your URL rewrite management

Answer (score 1):

If CMS page is not showing on the website then below options you could check:

1. The CMS page having url key "portfolio" should be enabled.
2. The Store view is set properly for the CMS page.
3. Try accessing CMS page by adding index.php in your base URL.
4. Check if any of your module having frontname same as your CMS page URL key. In your case it is "portfolio"